# Fill specific color in picture

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an image I'll call door.png, and it looks like this.

[image: This is the door.]

What I want to do is have the white part of the door be filled in with my desired color. I would like to do so to have better key and locks. How would I fill that white part of the map with oh say, 0xFF0000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop and [`.getPixel()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getPixel%28%29) to find the target pixels. You can then go ahead and use [`.setPixel()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#setPixel%28%29) on the found pixels to change them to a new colour.

In this specific scenario however, you could skip the first step and simply fill a circular area in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Make several doors of your wanted colors, or if you want to use a hex code for the color, draw it using vector graphics. Its scalable and looks better than raster graphics. Sprite and Shape have the property graphics, in which you draw those shapes with their colors & such.